# Why does Tesseract OCR return a non-existent character (digit) in the middle of number?

Tags: image, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using tesseract to collect the text in various small images that fall into different categories with specific classifications.

In this specific case I know it has to be a number and the language on the whole document is mostly German and some English.
I  want so get the number 85 from the following image:

[image: Input image]

But I get 835. Where is the 3 coming from?
I have the following parameters:

```
pt.image_to_string(crop_img_final, lang="deu+eng+osd", config="--psm 6 -c tessedit_use_primary_params_model=1 -c classify_bln_numeric_mode=1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.,")
```

I tried to drop some parametes, but that didn't change anything. Still the 3 in the middle.
I'm using tesseract 5.3.0.

It works fine on all of the other images, no added random numbers.